# ¿Alguna librería en java para componentes estilo metro UI?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Quiero una librería que tenga los componentes de swing pero que su estilo sea parecido a la interfaz metro que tiene windows 8 y windows 10.

Comment: probaste Java fx?

Comment: @rn3w hasta ahora sólo he usado swing y awt, sabés donde la puedo descargar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo recomendaría [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).

Es una librería gráfica que se puede utilizar directamente como código Java (Generando la interfaz desde el propio código Java) o utilizando FXML (Básicamente XML). La gran ventaja es que se le puede aplicar CSS, con lo que el aspecto de la interfaz se puede personalizar completamente.

Ésta viene incluida en los últimos JDKs, para utilizarla lo único que hace falta es instalar un JDK (8 preferiblemente, ya que es el más reciente, se puede descargar desde la misma página de oracle: [Aquí](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)).

Personalmente uso Eclipse, para facilitar la utilización de JavaFX en Eclipse utilizo un plugin llamado *e(fx)clipse 2.4.0*, se puede encontrar en el mismo *marketplace* de eclipse, y SceneBuilder, el cual es un programa independiente que te permite diseñar interfaces de forma visual, viene incluido (Si no me equivoco) en este *plugin*.